Can I define a provider scope without listing all providers in that scope in Angular?
I have some Angular services that store state, and I’d like these to be scoped to the appropriate component (and its subcomponents) to avoid leaking state between different instances of the same component. As there can be many services that exist in the same scope, and some are only referenced in lazy components, I’d like to specify the scope in the service rather than the scoping component.
The current two options I’m aware of are as follows:

Root provider
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) class FirstService {}

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) class SecondService {}

@Component({
  template: `@defer { <lazy-component /> }`
  imports: [LazyComponent],
}) class MyComponent {
  // same service instance for all MyComponent instances
  field = inject(FirstService)
}

@Component({}) class LazyComponent {
  // same service instance for all LazyComponent instances
  service = inject(SecondService);
}

This causes leaks between component instances, and is not tree-shakable for services not loaded in the first bundle.

Explicit component provider
@Injectable() class FirstService {}

@Injectable() class SecondService {}

@Component({
  template: `@defer { <lazy-component /> }`
  imports: [LazyComponent],
  providers: [FirstService, SecondService],
}) class MyComponent {
  // new service instance for each MyComponent instance
  field = inject(FirstService)
}

@Component({}) class LazyComponent {
  // new service instance for each MyComponent instance
  service = inject(SecondService);
}

This is correctly separated, but it requires listing every service, and all services are loaded, even if they are not needed, or first needed in a lazy-loaded module.


Ideal solution
@Injectable({ scope: 'modal' }) class FirstService {}

@Injectable({ scope: 'modal' }) class SecondService {}

@Component({
  template: `@defer { <lazy-component /> }`
  providerScopes: ['modal'],
  imports: [LazyComponent],
}) class MyComponent {
  // new service instance for each MyComponent instance
  service = inject(FirstService)
}

@Component({}) class LazyComponent {
  // new service instance for each MyComponent instance
  service = inject(SecondService);
}

This way the services are scoped correctly, but also not listed in the service, and so  can be lazy-loaded by child components.
Is there a way to achieve this?

The way I would do this is with route providers.

@MatthieuRiegler I’m not using Angular router, because I’m using Angular Elements and don’t have multiple pages.

Then you could go with component provided services ? It's a bit more verbose I agree.

@MatthieuRiegler That’s the second option I’ve given, but apart from being verbose, it also means that all classes scoped for a given component have to be loaded by that given component, even if they’re only used in the lazy child of that component.

The providedIn property accepts the following inputs.
@Injectable ({
  providedIn?: Type<any> | "root" | "platform" | "any" | null | undefined;
})

In the providedIn property you can also specify Type<any>, which will be the component you want to scope the service to. But you can only scope it to a single component using this method.
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LazyComponent, MyComponent } from './main';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: MyComponent,
})
export class FirstService {
  test = '';
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: LazyComponent,
})
export class SecondService {
  test = '';
}

But this does not mean it is included in the application, to ensure it is findable by dependency injection, we can add it to the root providers array or root module providers array. But the scope defined in providedIn scopes it to that particular component.
bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [FirstService, SecondService],
});

We can still import this service on other components, but it's guaranteed that the component you scoped it to has a separate instance.
Full Code:
services:
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FirstService, SecondService } from './services';

@Component({
  selector: 'lazy-component',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule],
  template: `
    <input [(ngModel)]="service.test"/>
    {{service.test}}
  `,
})
export class LazyComponent {
  service = inject(SecondService);
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [LazyComponent],
  template: `@defer { <lazy-component /> }`,
})
export class MyComponent {
  service = inject(FirstService);
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  imports: [FormsModule, MyComponent],
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <my-component/> 

    <input [(ngModel)]="service.test"/>
    {{service.test}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  service = inject(FirstService);
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [FirstService, SecondService],
});

Stackblitz Demo

Thanks @NarenMurali! Unfortunately it seems that usage of providedIn is deprecated, and leads to dependency cycles. And I’m not sure how this would solve the issue of lazy imports, as here all services are loaded at the root level

@CharlieHarding please share official docs saying its deprecated firstly. You want a separate instance without declaring it, what is the problem with my solution. what is it lacking?

@CharlieHarding either mine or Matthieu Riegler solution should solve your issue, one loads the services when the component is loaded, another loads the services on load itself

https://angular.dev/api/core/Injectable#providedIn “Type - associates the injectable with an @NgModule or other InjectorType. This option is DEPRECATED.”

@CharlieHarding Then Riegler approach is good enough right? what is the problem with the services loaded when the lazy loaded component is loaded

My problem with that solution is that I would like SecondService to be scoped to MyComponent, but only to be loaded when LazyComponent is loaded. His solution loads the service in MyComponent, meaning the service is not lazy-loaded, and if the service is no longer used anywhere, it is still loaded

@CharlieHarding If it's scoped to MyComponent it has to be rendered with MyComponent, where you scope it is where you use it. Why would you scope something to a parent component (not load it) and use it on the child component (load it there), what is it that you are trying to achieve
